# Alterar nome dos nodes e subnodes XML vindos de um array

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, xml

Tenho um array, que quero transformar num documento xml, já consegui com que fosse criado mas não consigo alterar os nomes de alguns nodes e sub-nodes, segue de seguida um exemplo de um array a ser transformado, o código que faz a transformação e um exemplo do xml que é criado.

**Exemplo do Array a ser transformado em XML:**

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
array(31) {
["idCandidato"]=>
string(2) "80"
["nome"]=>
string(14) "Vitor Bonzinho"
["genero"]=>
string(1) "M"
["nacionalidade"]=>
string(6) "Brasil"
["dataNascimento"]=>
string(10) "2017-02-15"
["tipoIdentificacao"]=>
string(18) "carteiraIdentidade"
["numeroIdentificacao"]=>
string(7) "7987987"
["cpf"]=>
string(6) "654654"
["validadeID"]=>
string(10) "2017-02-17"
["morada"]=>
string(20) "Rua do Mormugão 405"
["localidade"]=>
string(25) "S.mamede infesta , Lisboa"
["codPostal"]=>
string(8) "4465-213"
["pais_residencia"]=>
string(8) "Portugal"
["indicativoTlf"]=>
string(3) "123"
["numTelefone"]=>
string(9) "938353294"
["email"]=>
string(17) "bonzinho@fe.up.pt"
["codCurso"]=>
string(4) "M543"
["docID"]=>
string(114) "http://localhost/candidaturas/candi/mestrados_independentes/fileIdentificacao/facb9a2a4d31608e83888d97cda240d2.pdf"
["fileConclusaoCursoSuperior"]=>
string(123) "http://localhost/candidaturas/candi/mestrados_independentes/fileConclusaoCursoSuperior/c39dfe57ba49ac5d9eee19645a26eaef.pdf"
["fileCertidaoUnidadesCurriculares"]=>
string(129) "http://localhost/candidaturas/candi/mestrados_independentes/fileCertidaoUnidadesCurriculares/0863719cfe014f42a0f23b1576a69dce.pdf"
["fileCV"]=>
string(103) "http://localhost/candidaturas/candi/mestrados_independentes/fileCV/b1bf54e803c29bb555ffcc017019873b.pdf"
["fileCVPersonalizado"]=>
NULL
["filePortfolio"]=>
NULL
["fileCartaRecomendacao"]=>
string(118) "http://localhost/candidaturas/candi/mestrados_independentes/fileCartaRecomendacao/f489a61eada305dbb5f4d4c18090f829.pdf"
["fileCartaMotivacao"]=>
string(115) "http://localhost/candidaturas/candi/mestrados_independentes/fileCartaMotivacao/b8af87adcbac9b1208dea778159abad6.pdf"
["filePropostaProjeto"]=>
NULL
["fileCertificadoEN"]=>
NULL
["fileFotografia"]=>
NULL
["pagSucesso"]=>
string(1) "0"
["linguas"]=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(10) "Português"
    ["nivel"]=>
    string(8) "satisfaz"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(5) "Russo"
    ["nivel"]=>
    string(3) "bom"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(7) "Alemão"
    ["nivel"]=>
    string(9) "muito bom"
  }
}
["ramos"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cod_ramo"]=>
    string(3) "521"
    ["nome"]=>
    string(8) "Sólidos"
    ["opcao"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cod_ramo"]=>
    string(3) "522"
    ["nome"]=>
    string(8) "Fluídos"
    ["opcao"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
}
}
```

**Código PHP que uso para criar o XML:**

```
//function defination to convert array to xml
private function array_to_xml($array, &$xml_user_info) {
    $x = 0;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {  //$key nome do campo $value valor do campo
        if(is_array($value)) { // so entra na lingua e nos ramos
            if(!is_numeric($key)){ // se a $key não for um numero
                $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("$key");
                $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }else{
                $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("item$key");
                $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
        }else {
            $xml_user_info->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
    }
```

**Exemplo do XML criado:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No xml criado queria que o node marcado a azul se chama-se "candidato" , o node que está a vermelho se chama-se "ramo" e o node que está a verde se chama-se "lingua"

Comment: "Segue de sequida", "Se chama-se"? O que isso quer dizer? Você fala português? Está usando o _translate_?

Comment: Peço desculpa só reparei agora que se escrever <candidato></candidato> não aparece, ficando o espaço em branco, tinha escrito <candidato></candidato> <ramo></ramo> <lingua></lingua> e não mostrou nada nesse espaço, no entanto julgo que o nome de cada node não faria diferença na solução

Comment: Eu realmente achei que vc era estrangeiro. Mas já que conseguiu resolver, seria legal responder à sua própria pergunta com a solução e marcar sua resposta ;)

Comment: Onde leu que já resolvi?

Comment: é... então eu realmente não compreendo a língua que vc fala :D